# How to add a vertical line in a table row that has white space between top and bottom borders

Tags: html, css

As I said in the Title I want to add a vertical line in a table exactly like this :

[screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/HuGC4U3.jpg)

how I can add an white space to my vertical line like that.

my border-collapse is separate also.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/tkfduz2e/)

html :

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="no-vl"></td>
      <td class="vl"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

css :

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 5px;
}

td {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.vl {
  border-left: 6px solid green;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.no-vl {
  border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Please show what you've done so far.

Comment: here is exactly what I want : https://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/8t4ae2dw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted. You could use the `after` pseudo element of the `td` and achieve the desired effect

```css
td{
  padding:10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  border-width: 1px 0; 
}

table{
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td:after{
  content: '';
  border-right: 2px solid grey;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a vertical rule with the [**column-rule**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-rule) property:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  width: 90%;
  text-align: justify;
  column-count: 2;
  column-rule: 3px solid darkgrey;
  column-gap: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, error eligendi quibusdam placeat veniam? Doloremque quis id eveniet, nemo fugiat veritatis aspernatur consequuntur perspiciatis animi, aperiam asperiores dolorem adipisci ad labore quos aliquid
  voluptatibus vero alias natus, deserunt beatae. Repellat minus dolorem architecto provident alias perferendis nihil voluptatum odit ipsum, deleniti iusto, mollitia, atque aut, omnis enim maxime accusantium. Non, maxime. Odit culpa, sint explicabo dignissimos
  eum corporis.
</p>
```

Comment: thanks but I had wanted a vertical line in a table. this solution not work in tables